# Compiler error when adding core data to app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm adding core data to my app. In the following method, it says `Use of undeclared identifier NSSQLiteStoreType`

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"tdfas.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you have linked with CoreData and imported it...

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

Comment: That solved the problem.  But I copied the code from the core data new app template which didn't import that either?

Comment: @Jon you can add it to -Prefix.pch file in the "Supporting Files" group, just before the final #endif